# JaxB property value is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd, jaxb

I am using the following xsd schema file to generate java classes

```
<xsd:complexType name="Instruction">
<xsd:choice>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="InstructionIndicator" type="InstructionIndicator">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>some text</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="49">
            <xsd:element name="MultipleTimingModifier" type="ANDOR"
                minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>some text</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="TimingAndDuration" type="TimingAndDuration" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="AdministrationIndicator" type="AdministrationIndicator">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>some text</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="DoseAdministration" type="DoseAdministration" />
                <xsd:element name="TimingAndDuration" type="TimingAndDuration">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>some text</xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="49">
                    <xsd:element name="MultipleTimingModifier" type="ANDOR"
                        minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>some text</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="TimingAndDuration" type="TimingAndDuration" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:element name="IndicationForUse" type="Indication"
                maxOccurs="50">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>some text</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="IndicationClarifyingFreeText" type="an1..255"
                minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="MaximumDoseRestriction" type="MaximumDoseRestriction"
            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="50">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>some text</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:choice>
```

</xsd:complexType>

But processing this results in an error

> Property "MultipleTimingModifierAndTimingAndDuration" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.

To resolve this i wrote a binding file with following content

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" version="2.0">

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="structures.xsd"
    node="//xs:complexType[@name='Instruction']/xs:choice[1]
    /xs:sequence[1]/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='MultipleTimingModifier']">
    <jaxb:property name="MultipleTimingModifier1" />
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="structures.xsd"
    node="//xs:complexType[@name='Instruction']/xs:choice
    /xs:sequence[1]/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='TimingAndDuration']">
    <jaxb:property name="TimingAndDuration1" />
</jaxb:bindings>
```

</jaxb:bindings>

after adding this binding file while generating Jaxb classes in elcipse the following error is produced

> compiler was unable to honor this property customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.

the classes will successfully generate if maxoccurs="49" constraint is removed from targeted sequence node

Note:

- the schema is a combination of 5 different files and is of more then 2000 lines
- only the part in which error is produced is shared here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following binding code i have resolved my issue

```
<jaxb:bindings
     schemaLocation="structures.xsd"
     node="//xs:complexType[@name='Instruction']/xs:choice/xs:sequence[1]/xs:sequence[1]">
     <jaxb:property name="seq1"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```